# Are there any wrapper to get Tumblr data?

Tags: social-networking, tumblr

I'm a newbie in Tumblr.

Now, I need to get Tumblr data, such as post, photos...
I found the official document here : http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

This way is OK, but I wonder are there any wrapper client to getting these data ?
Such as Facebook SDK for Facebook.

Comment: For what language are you looking for a wrapper? Wrappers are built specific to programming languages

Comment: @Krimson :  am using Java.

Comment: I would also recommend the SDK @Dat_Nguyen suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the official SDK from Tumblr to develop you app. You can reference at: https://github.com/tumblr/jumblr